# Alogrithm to deterime if one set is a subset of another

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algorithms

Given $p$ and $q$ in any format desired, how could I deterime if $\{x \in \mathbb{R}:p(x)\} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{R}:q(x)\}$ is true using an algorithm. Obviously checking all elements of $\mathbb{R}$ is impossible. This problem is basically ewuivslent equivalent to determining the truth of $\forall x (p(x) \rightarrow q(x))$.Also, not all $p$ and $q$ would be possible. Pseudo code or python example would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you have further restrictions on $p$ and $q$, this is impossible. For examples, if $p$ is the condition satisfied by all rationals, and $q$ is the condition satisfied by all rationals except $r$ (pick your favorite 'large' one). You can check like mad, but unless you are really lucky, you are unable to conclude that $p$ is not contained in $q$. As a concrete example, $p$ is the condition that $0=0$, and $q$ is the condition that $\frac {1}{x-r} = \frac {1}{x-r}$.

Comment: Even if $x\in \mathbb{N}$, this is a difficult problem. Many interesting (and practical) digital circuit verification problems can be expressed this way (albeit awkwardly).

Comment: For infinite sets, you won't be able to check for particular elements so you need to be able to know if $p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$. Assuming you expressed $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ with $\land$, $\lnot$ and $\lor$ and a few other things, you should be able to get a deterministic algorithm that reduces $\lnot p(x) \lor q(x)$ as much as it can. If you get $true$, then $p(x) \Rightarrow q(x)$ and otherwise, if your algorithm is correct, not. But this would mean doing code for $=$, $<$, $\mid$ etc and how they relate to one another is $a|b\land b|a \Rightarrow |a|=|b|$ etc.

Comment: I never did anything like that but from what I heard, if you're going to do something like that, you might want to use Coq http://coq.inria.fr/

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible in general. For example, let $P$ be any undecidable statement. Then the statement

$$ \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = 0 \} \subseteq \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x = 0 \wedge P \} $$

is also undecidable.